# SpecFlow doesn't work on local machine; get a '*.feature.cs' could not be found

Tags: specflow

I am trying to set up a hello world project SpecFlow but I cannot seem to build and run the tests for my project. I have even sent my .sln to a colleague and it builds and runs perfectly on his machine.

We are both using Visual Studio 2019; I followed the 'Getting Started' page on spec flow website; I have 'Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator' set to False. I have the extension installed for Visual Studio 2019.

Example files: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow-Examples

When I go to build I get the following in the *.feature.cs file:

```
#error Could not find a reference to SpecFlow in project 'MyProject.Specs'.
#error Please add the 'TechTalk.SpecFlow' package to the project and use MSBuild generation instead of using SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator.
#error For more information see https://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which NuGet packages do  you have installed?

Comment: It turned out the most recent version of SpecFlow was actually bugged, I had to downgrade to 3.1.62 for it to work